# Hello World program for Google Glass - Step by Step

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I started reading stuff on Google Glass development one week ago, including [this](https://developers.google.com/glass/overview). However, I still could not find a tutorial to develop a "complete hello world program". What I meant by "complete" is; where to get the API, how to set up the API, how to write the hello world UI, how to write the code for the UI, how to install the emulator/simulator and test it. For an example, if you take a Java / Android / C++ / C# book, the first chapter is a hello world program, the "complete note" which explains how to develop it, step by step, making sure the new user is not in a mess. I went through the developer guide, and it is not what I am looking for.

Since I couldn't find anything, what I did is wrote the HTTP code in [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/playground), in the given small text box.

But I saw some people have developed code and tested it, so I would like to have "step-by-step guidance for writing Hello world for Google Glass". I am sure it will benefit a lot of new comers as well.

Please note that my favorite language is Java and Android, I do not have a Google Glass  and I am not a registered "glass explorer" (as they have asked [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/quickstart/java)) if it matters.

Please provide me step by step instructions / Link to step by step instructions for writing Hello world for Google Glass, because even after a one week of reading, I am totally empty handed, giving so much stress to my student life.

Comment: can't help you with complete tutorial but step 1 is definitely to get glass hw

Comment: Have you tried one of our [Quick Start samples](https://developers.google.com/glass/quickstart/index)?

Comment: @Alain: Thank you a lot for the reply. I tried to run them in android phone, no good. Does that mean there is no way we can simulate them using android phone? Apart from that, the entire UI is based on Java code. So like in android, can't we develop the UI using XML?

Comment: The code doesn't run on the device but on a server as the Mirror API is a web-based API. You can use your language of choice to interact with it and we even have a running version linked from the page I mentioned in the above comment.

Answer (score 11):

You say that your favorite language is Java and Android so I'm not sure if you are looking for a mirror-api solution or GDK solution. If you want a GDK solution I've created a hello world application and it can be downloaded here: https://github.com/DasCody/Hello-Glass

Answer (score 2):

From the sounds of it you're looking for a GDK solution.

- Start with the Android SDK here: http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html
- Then move onto the Glass GDK here: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/
- You can then find a step by step GDK "Hello World" article here: http://www.straza.co.uk/latest/google-glass-gdk-tutorial