# Hello World For Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass, android-resources, google-gdk, android-remoteview

I'm trying to build a simple Hello World GDK program for Google Glass. I've looked up everywhere, but all the samples I could find used "Timeline Manager", which was removed by Google after XE 16.

What I'm trying to do is to create a live card that shows texts (Hello world!) in the middle.
I've tried to modify codes from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887755/hello-world-program-for-google-glass-step-by-step) (HuskyHuskie's answer) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774275/helloworld-for-google-glass) (IsabelHM's answer)

However, no matter what I did, no option or voice command appeared on the glass even though the console showed that the program is installed on device.

What I mostly modified was take out the TimelineManager part and replace

`mLiveCard = mTimelineManager.createLiveCard(LIVE_CARD_ID);`
with 
`mLiveCard = new LiveCard(this,LIVE_CARD_ID);`

Also, I'm relatively new to Android. I don't quite understand how R.id.XXXX and R.layout.XXXX are missing from the resource. Do you need to define it in Manifest or what else?

The following is the onStartCommand method:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            RemoteViews aRV = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.card_text);
    if (mLiveCard == null) {
       // mLiveCard = mTimelineManager.createLiveCard(LIVE_CARD_ID);
        mLiveCard = new LiveCard(this,LIVE_CARD_ID);

        aRV.setTextViewText(R.id.main_text, INTRO);
        mLiveCard.setViews(aRV);



        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        mLiveCard.setAction(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mIntent, 0));
        mLiveCard.publish(LiveCard.PublishMode.REVEAL);
    } 
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Please don't let my Tumbleweed streak continue lol

Comment: Just throwing this out there; `R.xxx.xxx` is automatically generated by the android project. If you're using Eclipse with an Android project, then this should be generated when you save your source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it to work following [THIS](http://karanbalkar.com/2014/06/tutorial-83-hello-world-using-google-glass/)

Note that the Manifest is not entirely correct. You need to add this line in the Manifest after the XE16 update:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />
```

See the post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097828/why-is-my-voice-command-missing-from-the-ok-glass-menu-in-xe16) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using our official samples available on [GitHub](https://github.com/googleglass) and reading our [documentations](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/index) as all of those caveats are explained and handled.

If you are using the latest version of Android Studio, you can also easily create a new project through our available templates: `LiveCard` and `Immersion`.

1. Open Android Studio
2. Create a new project
3. Enter your project information: application name, package name, etc.
4. Select Glass as the form factor: make sure to unselect all the other form factors unless you want to develop for those devices as well.
5. Select the `Immersion Activity` or the `Simple Live Card` template
6. Build and run your new Hello World project on Glass!